# How to set EventArg for ICommand?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, viewmodel, icommand

in VM, set ICommand like:

```
  private RelayCommand<EventArgs> _myCommand = null;
    public RelayCommand<EventArgs> MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myCommand == null)
            {
                _myCommand = new RelayCommand<EventArgs>((e) =>
                {
                  //....
                }
                );                    
            }

            return _myCommand;
        }
    }
```

In xaml, binding to this command like

```
<Button Content="Test Command" Margin="2,0,2,0" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=InputTextBox, Path=Text}" />
```

then run the app. it say can't convert string to EventArgs.

How to set EventArgs for ICommand binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `RelayCommand<T>` I've only come across `RelayCommand`.

However it would seem that `RelayCommand<EventArgs>` can't possibly be useful.  I suspect that you would at least need `RelayCommand<string>`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried RelayCommand<string> for this issue as the solution. Seems fine.